# Docker: Unable to restore container created from public image

Tags: docker

I started the Docker image [cirrusci/flutter:latest](https://hub.docker.com/layers/cirrusci/flutter/latest/images/sha256-c80fba15b47dd59699b70a8e8904e3cc012c9a5ea27c7d02b19d16b3fbf8847c?context=explore) in interactive mode, and created a container named `Foo`. When the container was running, I connteced via Remote Desktop in VS Code, pulled the code I wanted to run in the container and installed dependencies etc. I created/modified some files and then stopped the container.

However, when I try to restart the container with `docker start Foo` it simply exits immediately and I am unable to restore the contents of the container.

What have I misunderstood, and how can I restart this container without it exiting immediately?

Comment: You've set yourself up to lose the work you've done, unfortunately.  Anything you do in an interactive shell in a container will be lost as soon as the container exits.  As such you should use debugging tools like `docker exec` sparingly, and definitely avoid installing software into a running container.  You might look at material like Docker's [Containerize an application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial for a more reproducible approach.

Comment: It should work. Can you provide the Docker command you ran to start the first container?

Comment: @jcragun I ran `docker run --rm -it  cirrusci/flutter:latest `

Comment: The `--rm` flag means the container is removed after exiting. That's probably why it won't start again. Although, Docker would have given a different error like "No such container: <image id>".